# execution failed for task ' transformclasseswithdexfordebug'

Tags: android

> **Error 1**
>   : Esto me pasa al ejecutar mi proyecto.

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; El marcador en el documento que precede al elemento raíz debe tener el formato correcto.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Error 2** no me deja crear activitys

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />

<application
    android:name=".Variables_HassMovil"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logotipo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Precarga_HassMovil"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Inicio_HassMovil"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_inicio__hass_movil"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Calibracion_HassMovil"
        android:label="Calcular Precio"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cortes_Registro">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Cortes_Registro" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cortes_Registro"
        android:label="Registrar Corte"
        android:parentActivityName=".Inicio_HassMovil">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Inicio_HassMovil" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cortes_Seleccion"
        android:parentActivityName=".Inicio_HassMovil">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Inicio_HassMovil" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cortes_Confirmar"
        android:label="Confirmar Corte"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cortes_Seleccion">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Cortes_Seleccion" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Cortes_Descripcion"
        android:label="Descripcion"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cortes_Registro">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Cortes_Registro" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Precios_Configurar"
        android:label="Precios Generales"
        android:parentActivityName=".Inicio_HassMovil">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Inicio_HassMovil" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Empaques_Registrar"
        android:label="Nuevo Empaque"
        android:parentActivityName=".Empaques_Listado">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Empaques_Listado" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Empaques_Listado"
        android:label="Empaques"
        android:parentActivityName=".Inicio_HassMovil">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Inicio_HassMovil" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Precios_Empaques"
        android:label="Precio por empaque"
        android:parentActivityName=".Inicio_HassMovil">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Inicio_HassMovil" />
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Dispositivos_Localizacion"
        android:label="Localización"
        android:parentActivityName=".Cortes_Seleccion">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Cortes_Seleccion" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Realizaste cambios es así?  Quita el espacio de la primera línea, vuelve a construir el proyecto  Build > Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 2):

> El marcador en el documento que precede al elemento raíz debe tener el
>   formato correcto.

Se tiene un problema en el AndroidManifest.xml, revisando el contenido no se puede ver a simple vista un problema en la formación del .xml, te sugiero revises y asegures la primera linea de tu archivo sea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

ademas el error indica linea 1, columna 2, asegura que la linea este justificada a la izquierda, en ese espacio pudieras tener un carácter no imprimible.

ya que es muy común que se tenga un espacio y provoque problemas para construir el proyecto.

Si tu AndroidManifest.xml esta corregido seguramente necesites,

`Build` > `Rebuild Project`

con esto funcionará sin problemas.

Comment: hola Jorgesys, todo esta perfectamente alineado como me lo indicas, aun así me sigue marcando error.

Comment: Si, pero realizaste : Build > Rebuild Project y vuelve a ejecutar tu proyecto.

Comment: lo hago y me tira el siguiente error:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
    > Unable to delete directory: C:\Users\Administracion\Desktop\HassMovil\app\build\intermediates

Comment: Reinicia Android Studio